# Getting System.InvalidOperationException when sending an email using Exchange Web service

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send a reply email using Exchange WebService and got blocked with the below exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=This operation can't be performed because this service object already has an ID. To update this service object, use the Update() method instead.
  Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.ThrowIfThisIsNotNew()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Save(FolderId parentFolderId)
   at DataLoadLibrary.DataLoad.Email.EWSOAuthAdapter.genericEmail(String recepient, String subject, String bodyMessage, Dictionary`2 replacementStrings, String cc, String bcc, String headerMessage, String footerMessage, FileInfo[] attachments, String[] filenames, EmailMessage originalEmail, ExchangeService exchangeClient) in C:\Path\DataLoadLibrary\DataLoad\Email\EWSOAuthAdapter.cs:line 95
   at DataLoadLibrary.DataLoad.Email.OAuthBasedTestPortRequest.startDataload() in C:\Path\DataLoadLibrary\DataLoad\Email\OAuthBasedTestPortRequest.cs:line 132
   at TestPortEmailReader.Program.<Main>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Path\TestPortEmailReader\Program.cs:line 93

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    DataLoadLibrary.DataLoad.Email.EWSOAuthAdapter.genericEmail(string, string, string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>, string, string, string, string, System.IO.FileInfo[], string[], Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService) in EWSOAuthAdapter.cs
    DataLoadLibrary.DataLoad.Email.OAuthBasedTestPortRequest.startDataload() in OAuthBasedTestPortRequest.cs
    TestPortEmailReader.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

#Implementation

```
 public bool genericEmail(
                                string recepient,
                                string subject,
                                string bodyMessage,
                                Dictionary<string, string> replacementStrings = null,
                                string cc = "",
                                string bcc = "",
                                string headerMessage = "",
                                string footerMessage = "",
                                FileInfo[] attachments = null,
                                string[] filenames = null,
                                EmailMessage originalEmail = null,
                                ExchangeService exchangeClient = null)
        {

            
            EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeClient, originalEmail.Id, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
         
            //exchangeClient.LoadPropertiesForItems((IEnumerable<Item>)email, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

            email.Sender.Address = config.exchangeUsername + "@domain.com";
            email.Sender.Name = "ABC";
            if (recepient.Length == 0)
            {
                email.ToRecipients.Add(iPACTTeamEmail);
            }
            else
            {
                email.ToRecipients.Add(recepient.TrimEnd(';'));
            }
            if (cc.Length != 0)
                email.CcRecipients.Add(cc.TrimEnd(';'));
            if (config.environment != "PR")
            {
                email.Sender.Address = config.exchangeUsername + "@domain.com";
                email.CcRecipients.Add(null);
            }

            if (attachments != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (FileInfo fi in attachments)
                {
                    FileStream theStream = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    if (filenames == null)
                        email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(fi.Name, theStream);
                    else
                        email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(filenames[i], theStream);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (originalEmail != null)
            {
                string originalEmailFilename = config.extractFolder + "\\Emails" + originalEmail.Subject.Trim().Replace('\\', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace(":", "_").Replace("\"", "_").Replace("*", "_").Replace("?", "_").Replace("<", "_").Replace(">", "_").Replace("|", "_") + "_" + originalEmail.DateTimeReceived.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".msg";
                originalEmail.Save(originalEmailFilename); //Getting above exception here
                email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(originalEmailFilename);

            }

            if (config.environment == "PR")
                email.Subject = subject.Trim();
            else
                email.Subject = "[" + config.environment + "] " + subject.Trim();

            if (replacementStrings != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in replacementStrings)
                {
                    bodyMessage = bodyMessage.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                }
            }

            bodyMessage = bodyMessage.Replace("{headerMessage}", headerMessage);
            bodyMessage = bodyMessage.Replace("{footerMessage}", footerMessage);

            email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, bodyMessage);
            email.Send();

            return true;
        }
```

Even after binding the mail id am getting the same exception when saving the original email. Is it because am trying to save it multiple times. I went through this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4beb7588-f851-4c7d-b060-f46ae2642e61/get-email-message-after-send-it-with-exchange-library?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment but didn't get a proper solution.
Kindly help me to identify what is missing in my implementation

Comment: @Glen Getting this exception Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message.'

Answer (score 0):

```
            string originalEmailFilename = config.extractFolder + "\\Emails" + originalEmail.Subject.Trim().Replace('\\', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace(":", "_").Replace("\"", "_").Replace("*", "_").Replace("?", "_").Replace("<", "_").Replace(">", "_").Replace("|", "_") + "_" + originalEmail.DateTimeReceived.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".msg";
            originalEmail.Save(originalEmailFilename); //
```

You can't do this in the EWS Managed API as it doesn't support saving a Message to a file, also if you want an Msg file then EWS won't work for that at all this is an Office file format (compound ole file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/containers-compound-files?view=msvc-170). You can save a Message as an Eml file using Mime Stream as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: Getting this `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message.'`

Comment: You setting a Sender address and then using send why are you doing this ? the error is saying that you don't have rights to send as the email your trying to use in the sender address.